# access level redirecting not working well

Tags: php, pdo

i have a login page inside my index.php the login function is working well but the problem is the restriction on guest and admin,when i login as user or admin they go to there respected page but when i try to type in the url of guest.php or admin.php they can both access it should not access it,what i whant to happen here is that when i login as user only the guest page that the user can access the same as the admin..

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';

    if($userlevel->is_loggedin()!=""){
        $userlevel->redirect('guest.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

       $uname = $_POST['user'];
       $upass = $_POST['pass'];

       if($userlevel->login($uname,$upass)){
          switch($_SESSION['user_level']) {
             case "0": $userlevel->redirect('guest.php');
             break;
             case "1": $userlevel->redirect('admin.php');
             break;
          }
       }
    }
```

**guest.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';

    if(!$userlevel->is_loggedin()){
       $userlevel->redirect('index.php');
    }
    $ID = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM survey_section WHERE ID=:ID");
    $stmt->execute(array(":ID"=>$ID));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      
?>
```

**admin.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';

    if(!$userlevel->is_loggedin()){
         $userlevel->redirect('index.php');
    }
    $ID = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM survey_section WHERE ID=:ID");
    $stmt->execute(array(":ID"=>$ID));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

**i think one of my problem is here:**

```
if($userlevel->is_loggedin()!=""){
    $userlevel->redirect('guest.php');
}
```

because as you can it only redirect the guest.php but i don't know how to get this to wotk..

Comment: You're not doing any restriction in those pages....that's why they can both access each. How is this any different to the last 4/5 questions you've asked.... they all apply the same logic.

Comment: @Darren i'm sorry for this but really do not know why its not working..please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the privilege inside guest.php and admin.php

since you have a session variable named user_level, you can get the value of it in any page. Here's what you're going to do.

**guest.php**

```
<?php
  include_once 'db.php';

if($_SESSION['user_level'] == "1"){
   // it means admin
   $userlevel->redirect('admin.php');
}

if(!$userlevel->is_loggedin()){
   $userlevel->redirect('index.php');
}
$ID = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM survey_section WHERE ID=:ID");
$stmt->execute(array(":ID"=>$ID));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  ?>
```

The same as the **admin.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';

   if($_SESSION['user_level'] == "0"){
       // it means guest
       $userlevel->redirect('guest.php');
   }


    if(!$userlevel->is_loggedin()){
         $userlevel->redirect('index.php');
    }
    $ID = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM survey_section WHERE ID=:ID");
    $stmt->execute(array(":ID"=>$ID));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Comment: i have a question what if i have a home.php and the only user that can access it is the guest do i just need to copy your code and paste it to the home.php?

Comment: yup. That way you can apply restriction on your page.

Comment: then this will i put in my home.php right? if($_SESSION['user_level'] == "1"){
   // it means admin
   $userlevel->redirect('admin.php');
}

Comment: thanks..i'm working this for a long time..thank you very much..helped me a lot....